# JavaScript rapidly change background-img property without performance issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I have a script which changes the `background-img` property of multiple divs, every 20ms.

```js
var frames = ["57.png", "59.png", "60.png"]
var currentframe = 0;

var frame_loop = setInterval(function () {
    if (currentframe == 3) {
        currentframe = 0;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < $(".my-element").length; i++) {
            $(`.my-element:nth-child(${i + 1})`).css("background-image", `url(assets/loop/${frames[currentframe]})`);
        }
        currentframe++;
    }
}, 20);
```

The script above works as it should, however I experience some performance issues - and i'm assuming it's because the `background-img` is changing quite fast.

Is there anyway I could fix this issue? I don't mind using libraries. Would I need to resort to using gifs? Is it possible to use gifs with `background-img`?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Using a GIF would probably help (yes, you can set it as a background image), otherwise you could try replacing your `setInterval` with `requestAnimationFrame`, which will adapt itself to the frame rate. I would also recommend storing your DOM elements in a variable once at the start, and then simply using these variables, instead of looking them up in the DOM every time, which is very costly. Using vanillaJS instead of jQuery _might_ also give a minor improvement

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will use your suggestions to try and find an optimal solution.

Comment: Using more (as in libraries) would (probably) make thing worse...

Comment: I used APNG, and it seems to work much better. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I would do it *(may not be the most performant, but might help)*:

```js
var frames = [
  "https://a.wattpad.com/useravatar/Kitten6416.256.440418.jpg",
  "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/b5/e1/be/b5e1bef76b2058910f556c85c1040b79.jpg",
  "https://a.wattpad.com/useravatar/Vendedora_De_Meng.128.220869.jpg"
];

var currentFrame = 0,
    loopRunning = confirm("Warning! This page might trigger epileptic seizures. Continue?"),
    // Don't calculate those every time
    elems = document.querySelectorAll('.my-element'),
    nbElems = elems.length;

(function frame_loop() {
  if (loopRunning) {
    // Calculate this once before the loop
    var background = `url(${frames[currentFrame]})`;
    for (var i = 0; i < nbElems; i++) {
      elems[i].style.backgroundImage = background;
    }
    currentFrame = ++currentFrame % nbElems;
    requestAnimationFrame(frame_loop);
  }
})();
```

```css
.my-element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-element"></div>
<div class="my-element"></div>
<div class="my-element"></div>
```